# Including MathJax script in headers of Blazor app does not render MathML

Tags: mathjax, blazor

I am trying to show MathML equations using MathJax. I have included the script reference for MathML in the head portion. For Razor pages application, MathML is rendered properly. In Blazor (server side app), it shows as plain linear text.

When I refresh the page, it seems like it renders the MathML correctly but quickly reverts to plain text.

I am using .NET Core 3.0. I have also tried it on .NET Core 2.2 but does not work either.
Using the script below does not work...

```
<script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=es6"></script>
<script id="MathJax-script" async src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/mml-svg.js"></script>
```

but if I use this instead,

```
<script type="text/javascript" async src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.2/MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML"></script>
```

it works **only** after page is refreshed manually.

```
<p>
    <math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" display="block">
        <mi>x</mi> <mo>=</mo>
        <mrow>
            <mfrac>
                <mrow>
                    <mo>&#x2212;</mo>
                    <mi>b</mi>
                    <mo>&#x00B1;</mo>
                    <msqrt>
                        <msup><mi>b</mi><mn>2</mn></msup>
                        <mo>&#x2212;</mo>
                        <mn>4</mn><mi>a</mi><mi>c</mi>
                    </msqrt>
                </mrow>
                <mrow>
                    <mn>2</mn><mi>a</mi>
                </mrow>
            </mfrac>
        </mrow>
        <mtext>.</mtext>
    </math>
</p>
```

Instead of showing the value of x of quadratic equation, it shows "x = − b ± b2 − 4ac 2a ." All math symbols / formatting are omitted.

If I refresh the page, then the MathML formatting is rendered properly. If I navigate to other pages and back to the page with MathML, page has to be refreshed in order to see the correct rendering.

Comment: Any success on getting this to work with MathJax 3?

Comment: no, same issue remains.

Comment: Since then I've worked out some keys to using MathJax with Blazor... see here:
https://github.com/limefrogyank/MathJaxBlazor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic answer is that MathJax used this way is not going to work in Blazor.  Anything that modifies the DOM is going to conflict with Blazor.

As soon as a Blazor re-render occurs, Blazor is going to wonder what happened to the  tags that used to be there that MathJax removed.

Either:

1. You need to render this as part of a component where the MathML is not part of the DOM but rather a string parameter to your component.
2. For every re-render, you need to undo what MathJax has done to the page, let it re-render, then re-do MathJax's stuff.

I've done #1 for both Tex and MathML.  For #2, I've only done this with Tex formatting... I haven't been able to get it to work with MathML yet.  See how in my repo or just try the Nuget package.

https://github.com/limefrogyank/MathJaxBlazor

Comment: I was trying out mathml syntax in simple Razor pages but it is not working. You're saying that the problem is Razor page's being rendered and somehow cancels out mathml tag and make them plain text. So  if I put mathml text into an html component after the document is ready and full loaded, it would work ?

Comment: Not exactly.  Blazor tracks what has been rendered and will re-render components on any parameter change in that component or any parent.  So if you use MathJax's standard way to render mathml (which is to wait until page load, then look for the $$ or whatever markers you set), whatever mathml is created will get wiped out by the next render pass by Blazor.  So you have to manually render mathML as part of Blazor's lifecycle.  That's what my library was intended to do.  (Although it needs updating to the lastest version of Blazor)

Comment: FYI, I updated the library mentioned above so that the demo works with the latest version of Blazor and it needs no other components (removed BlazorFabric stuff)
https://yellow-grass-06f48d51e.azurestaticapps.net/

Comment: Thanks for explanation.  I've downloaded the demo project and learning about this solution.